# Tableview with Navigation bar

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 4.5.2.I have created a customization tableview programmatically.When i click on a row I need to move to next view.Is there a way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to move into another view controller while tapping on table view cell.

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
```

Comment: karthi you don't need points to accept the answer you just need to tick on the correct button to accept the answer.